# iOS 7 parallax effect in my view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parallax

I'm developing an app for iOS 7 in Objective-C. I've got a screen in my app with a few buttons and a pretty background image. (It's a simple xib with `UIButtons` on top of a `UIImageView`.)

I was thinking that it'd be cool if those buttons had the parallax effect that the iOS 7 home screen has, so if you tilt the phone you could see the background.

How can I implement that effect in my own app?

Comment: Have a look at this library : https://github.com/Przytua/UIView-MWParallax

Comment: For swift, try with that: https://github.com/ArvindPrakashJoshi/AJParallaxEffect

Answer (score 274, accepted):

With iOS 7, Apple introduced [`UIMotionEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMotionEffect_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIMotionEffect) to add Motion effects that are related to the orientation of the user’s device. For example, to emulate the parallax effect on the home screen, you can use the subclass [`UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInterpolatingMotionEffect_class/Reference/Reference.html), as explained [here](http://kevinyavno.com/blog/?p=127), just with a few lines of code.

**Objective-C**:

```
// Set vertical effect
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = 
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] 
  initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
             type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-10);
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(10);

// Set horizontal effect 
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = 
  [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] 
  initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"     
             type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-10);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(10);
  
// Create group to combine both
UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];

// Add both effects to your view
[myBackgroundView addMotionEffect:group];
```

**Swift** (Thanks to @Lucas):

```
// Set vertical effect
let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y",
type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -10
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 10

// Set horizontal effect
let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x",
    type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -10
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = 10

// Create group to combine both
let group = UIMotionEffectGroup()
group.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]

// Add both effects to your view
myBackgroundView.addMotionEffect(group)
```

Also, you can find a bunch of libraries to do this easier or to add this functionality to older iOS versions:

- [NGAParallaxMotion](https://github.com/michaeljbishop/NGAParallaxMotion) (requires **iOS 7**).
- [DVParallaxView](https://github.com/denivip/DVParallaxView) (requires **iOS 5.0** or higher and **ARC**).
- [MKParallaxView](https://github.com/Morgan-Kennedy/MKParallaxView) (tested with **iOS 6.0**, requires **ARC**).
- [UIView-MWParallax](https://github.com/Przytua/UIView-MWParallax) (tested with **iOS 6.1**, requires **ARC**).

Comment: NGAParallaxMotion is for iOS 7+, not for older iOS versions. It provides a category for UIView, allowing you to set a .parallaxIntensity value, setting up the UIMotionEffect parameters with one line of code.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the answer to include supported versions and requirements.

Comment: Actually, you want to add the motion effect to the background view, not the front view.  But other than that, this code works great!  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @gstroup! I have updated the code to be 'myBackgroundView'.

Comment: Does anyone know how to check if the user has disabled the effects? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132000/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-parallax-effect-is-disabled-in-ios-7

Comment: @gstroup Actually, on the home screen both the foreground and the background are moving. But if you were to chose only one layer to apply the parallax effect to, I agree the background would probably be best.

Comment: @veducm: What about a parallax pinch zoom effect, how will this be done?

Comment: @dcone: not sure [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9167644/1264909) is what you are looking for. Otherwise, could you please give an example to understand what you want?

Comment: This worked right away, in a way that was exactly what I was after. Thank you so much!

Comment: An important configuration that is necessary to think about for anyone using parallax, is that you need to consider the Z-axis layering of the view. If the view is to look "above", you will have a minimumRelativeValue less than the maximumRelativeValue. If the view is to look "behind" (such as iOS home/lock screen), then the values are to be reversed.

Comment: Any ideas how to apply this so it just moves a single sprite kit SKSpriteNode inside an SKScene, rather than a whole view moving?

Answer (score 16):

Translated to swift in case anyone is lazy. Please vote @veducm [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067717/676822) up if you found this useful

```
@IBOutlet var background : UIImageView!

func parallaxEffectOnBackground() {
    let relativeMotionValue = 50
    var verticalMotionEffect : UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y",
        type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -relativeMotionValue
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = relativeMotionValue

    var horizontalMotionEffect : UIInterpolatingMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x",
        type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -relativeMotionValue
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = relativeMotionValue

    var group : UIMotionEffectGroup = UIMotionEffectGroup()
    group.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]

    self.background.addMotionEffect(group)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas! I have updated my answer to include the swift sample too. It is based on this one. Feel free to review it and do any changes needed.

Answer (score 7):

@veducm's solution can be a little shorter. The UIMotionEffectGroup for its x and y motion is obsolete if you add the the x and y-axis motionEffects separately.

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *motionEffect;
motionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"
                                                               type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
motionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-25);
motionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(25);
[bgView addMotionEffect:motionEffect];

motionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
                                                               type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
motionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-25);
motionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(25);
[bgView addMotionEffect:motionEffect];
```

Comment: Just as a heads up if anyone is using this shortened version, the first motion effect needs to have a `type` of `UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis` and not `UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis` as it is in the code laid out

Comment: @BooHoo Adding them as a group is obsolete? Where do you see that? As of the time of this writing the Apple docs don't have anything about it being obsolete. The whole purpose of grouping them is to improve performance. All effects in the group are rendered once. When you apply them separately, they must be rendered separately. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong (and point me to Apple's documentation on it.)

Answer (score 6):

```
const static CGFloat kCustomIOS7MotionEffectExtent = 10.0; 

- (void)applyMotionEffects:(UIView *YOUR_VIEW) {
     if (NSClassFromString(@"UIInterpolatingMotionEffect")) {
         UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"
                                                                                                        type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
         horizontalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-kCustomIOS7MotionEffectExtent);
         horizontalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @( kCustomIOS7MotionEffectExtent);
         UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
                                                                                                      type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
         verticalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-kCustomIOS7MotionEffectExtent);
         verticalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @( kCustomIOS7MotionEffectExtent);
         UIMotionEffectGroup *motionEffectGroup = [[UIMotionEffectGroup alloc] init];
         motionEffectGroup.motionEffects = @[horizontalEffect, verticalEffect]; 
         [YOUR_VIEW addMotionEffect:motionEffectGroup];
     }
}
```

Comment: @Rob according to your suggestion updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

Here is an easy category to integrate the effect on iOs7+ :

```
NSString *const centerX = @"center.x";
NSString *const centerY = @"center.y";

//#define IS_OS_7_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)

@implementation UIView (TLMotionEffect)

- (void)addCenterMotionEffectsXYWithOffset:(CGFloat)offset {

//    if(!IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) return;
    if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) return;

    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *xAxis;
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *yAxis;

    xAxis = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:centerX type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
    xAxis.maximumRelativeValue = @(offset);
    xAxis.minimumRelativeValue = @(-offset);

    yAxis = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:centerY type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    yAxis.minimumRelativeValue = @(-offset);
    yAxis.maximumRelativeValue = @(offset);

    UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [[UIMotionEffectGroup alloc] init];
    group.motionEffects = @[xAxis, yAxis];

    [self addMotionEffect:group];
}

@end
```

https://github.com/jvenegas/TLMotionEffect

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It will be hard to integrate the whole github project here

Comment: You don't have to bring the whole project, only the essential part like i demonstrated by editing the answer. This is so that the code sticks around in case Github is down, you pull the repo or the sky falls down.

Answer (score 4):

UIMotionEffect provides a free parallax implementation on iOS 7.

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uimotioneffect/

https://github.com/michaeljbishop/NGAParallaxMotion lets you just set the parallax intensity.

Answer (score 3):

**This will help someone who is looking to implement parallax for tableView or collectionView.**

> - first of all create the cell for the tableview and put the image view in it.
> - set the image height slightly more than the cell height. if cell height = 160 let the image height be 200 (to make the parallax effect and you can change it accordingly)
> - put this two variable in your viewController or any class where your tableView delegate is extended

```
let imageHeight:CGFloat = 150.0
let OffsetSpeed: CGFloat = 25.0
```

> - add the following code in the same class

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //  print("inside scroll")

    if let visibleCells = seriesTabelView.visibleCells as? [SeriesTableViewCell] {
        for parallaxCell in visibleCells {
            var yOffset = ((seriesTabelView.contentOffset.y - parallaxCell.frame.origin.y) / imageHeight) * OffsetSpeedTwo
            parallaxCell.offset(CGPointMake(0.0, yOffset))
        }
    }
}
```

> - where seriesTabelView is my UItableview
> - and now lets goto the cell of this tableView and add the following code

```
func offset(offset: CGPoint) {
        posterImage.frame = CGRectOffset(self.posterImage.bounds, offset.x, offset.y)
    }
```

> - were posterImage is my UIImageView

**If you want to implement this to collectionView just change the tableView vairable to your collectionView variable**

and thats it. i am not sure if this is the best way. but it works for me. hope it works for you too. and let me know if there is any problem

Answer (score 2):

Really dam **easy** to do so why refers complex code. just try it. **Working**

Take a view on imageview exactly size of image view.
by default alpha for view set 0.

```
//MARK: Scroll View Delegate methods
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

NSLog(@"X: %f Y: %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x,scrollView.contentOffset.y);

CGFloat scrollY = _mainScrollView.contentOffset.y;
CGFloat height = _alphaView.frame.size.height;

CGFloat alphaMonitor = scrollY/height;

_alphaView.alpha = alphaMonitor;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift translation:

```
// Set vertical effect
let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: .TiltAlongVerticalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -value
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = value

// Set vertical effect
let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .TiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = -value
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = value

let group = UIMotionEffectGroup()
group.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]
self.motionEffect = group
self.addMotionEffect(group)
```