# is it possible to detect if parallax effect is disabled in ios 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

user can disable parallax effect by switching  Settings -> General -> Accessibility: Reduce Motion: On.  after this `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` doesn't have any effect. is there any way to handle this case? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: what are the values of `minimumRelativeValue` & `maximumRelativeValue` after disabling the effect?

Comment: minimumRelativeValue & maximumRelativeValue does not change

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Comment: No, i've searched a lot and i think this isn't possible

Comment: I've submitted a feature request to Apple. You should too.

Comment: @Eric and sheraza, just curious, why do you guys need to know if this is turned on or off? You should not have features dependent on this. Remember that iPhone 4 devices have this disabled always.

Comment: Not features but design. A client requested parallax and I want to be able to tell them we can show an UIAlertView if they've disabled parallax. I submitted a feature request to Apple.