# How to obtain parallax motion offset similar to iOS 7 home screen with support for iOS 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, parallax

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972994/ios-7-parallax-effect-in-my-view-controller) that iOS 7 offers a simple way to get parallax motion offsets. But it also shows you have to apply it to a UIView.

I need it for something different (a drawing algorithm). What would you do to obtain the pure CGPoint parallax motion offset if you would not want to create a hidden view just to obtain the value?

And how could I get this parallax motion offset so it also runs with iOS 6?

Comment: YOU CAN USE THIS https://github.com/Przytua/UIView-MWParallax

Comment: it runs for iOS 6 as well

Comment: Thank you @KunalBalani but I need somthing that does NOT require to setup a UIView. I simply want the raw parallax offset value for a different purpose. Think of a controller. UIView-MWParallax is a category on UIView and only works with UIView. To get the parallax offset I would have to create a dummy view and then query its position.

Comment: Converting the code @KunalBalani references from a `UIView` category to an independent object looks pretty trivial. Just change it to its own class, see what fails to compile, and cleanup a little. The one major change would be to replace the `transform` settings to a point in `motionsUpdated`, but again, that's pretty trivial. It certainly looks like a good starting point.

Comment: Use the Accelerometer, or Motion API, and utilize CATransform3D on a **rasterised** layer according to the updates fired by the sensor/s?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is 3 years too late.

But, you could subclass `UIMotionEffect` and override `keyPathsAndRelativeValues(forViewerOffset:)` and implement whatever effect you want to apply to the view based on the viewer's viewing position.

The parameter `viewerOffset` provides an instance of `UIOffset` which will give you the viewing offset of the viewer. You need to return a dictionary with keyPaths as keys and the corresponding values that you compute based on the `viewerOffset` as the values for any of the animatable properties of the view.

```
import UIKit

class CustomMotionEffect: UIMotionEffect {

    override func keyPathsAndRelativeValues(forViewerOffset viewerOffset: UIOffset) -> [String : Any]? {
        var motionEffectDictionary = [String : Any]()

        //Horizontal
        if viewerOffset.horizontal > 0 { //Device tilted right

        } else if viewerOffset.horizontal < 0 { //Device tilted leftß

        } else {//Device horizontally perpendicular

        }

        //Vertical
        if viewerOffset.vertical > 0 { //Device tilted down

        } else if viewerOffset.vertical < 0 { //Device tilted up

        } else { //Device vertically perpendicular

        }
        return motionEffectDictionary
    }

}
```

Doing this will ensure you have control over how your effect should behave. But, this won't work on iOS6.