# How to set dynamic background for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting to place a background on my application and was wondering if there's a way to use one of the dynamic backgrounds like those that are provided as default wallpaper options. Is there any way to make that possible?

Comment: Yes there is. You can start by reading this: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uimotioneffect/

Comment: Look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972994/ios-7-parallax-effect-in-my-view-controller

Comment: @desdenova, I think you should add your comment as an answer

Comment: Those are all ways to do a Parallax background, not a Dynamic background.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a solid colour then set the background colour using `setBackgroundColor`.

In case you want an image then use `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]]`;

Hint : Save and Pick the value of the colour/ image from NSUsersDefaults.

Comment: How is a solid color a "dynamic background"?