# Adding parallax effect to image

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, parallax

This is the situation: [image]

I got the two image view on top of the view, and on the bottom is a container view (the one with the segmented control) that can be dragged upward.

Now, is there a way to add a parallax effect to the background image (the one with the blur) as I drag the container upward?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7 parallax effect in my view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972994/ios-7-parallax-effect-in-my-view-controller)

Answer (score 1):

A I can see you are working on iOS 9 so you can use InterploationMotionEffect available from iOS 8. I have also created example for the same  [ParallaxEffectExample](https://github.com/Gagan5278/ParallaxEffect)

Example is in swift & having two example set. First one as manual & second one using InterploationMotionEffect in UITableView.

Comment: Ohh..It's my fault in Git Upload.. By the way you can access following links
https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController
 
Parallax effect in CollectionView
https://github.com/mayuur/MJParallaxCollectionView

Comment: Also try to pull Git repository using https://github.com/Gagan5278/ParallaxEffect.git